# Transparent form bootstrap over background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap and can't figure out how to get texts and forms to overlay my background image. I've tried other solutions found here, but none of them work. I've tried adding to the bootstrap page as well as creating my own CSS and trying in the html page as well.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-xs-2">First Name</label>
        <div class = "col-xs-10">
            <input type = "text" class="form-control transparent-input" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for="inputLast" class="control-label col-xs-2">Last Name</label>
        <div class = "col-xs-10">
            <input type = "text" class="form-control transparent-input" id="inputLast" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control transparent-input" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control transparent-input" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-5">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My CSS

```
html{
    /* This image will be displayed fullscreen */
    /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
    min-height:100%;

    /* The Magic */
    background-size:cover;

    background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.7) url('bowling.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

body{
    /* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
    min-height:100%;
}

.transparent-input {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put a container around the form, make that container `100vh` and you can use a `background-image` declaration on it. It's more reliable to target a `<section>` or `<div>` than `html`.

I wired it all up on Codepen for you: http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/jWjgaO

Comment: I tried it, but I get a selector expected error on.form-horizontal, .form-group,  {
    background: none;
}

Comment: Can you post the error you are seeing? Better yet, put your code into a codepen instance and I can debug it there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your html markup like below (assign an id tag for the `body` element)

```
<body id="register-bg">
   <form class="form-horizontal">
      .....
      .....
  </form>
</body>
```

And your CSS would be like

```
    html {
        /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        /* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
        min-height: 100%;
    }
        body#register-bg {
            /* This image will be displayed fullscreen */
            /* The Magic */
            background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.7) url('bowling.jpg') no-repeat center center;
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
        }
    .transparent-input {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border: none;
    }
```